# React Native FlatList duplicating data in renderItem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using Firebase and redux to update an array and display it in a flatlist. The fetch call is being made in `componentWillMount()` and I can see that the data is being fetched correctly. However, looking in `_myTestRender` method, it is called twice for each item in `this.props.test`.

Sample data:

```
[{'name':'test1', stuff: [{'key':'Bob'},{'key':'Alice'}]}]
```

Render:

```
console.log('RENDER');
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        data={this.props.test}
        renderItem={({item}) => this._myTestRender(item)} />
      <Button title="log props" onPress={this._logProps} />
    </View>
  </View>
 )
}
```

_keyExtractor

```
_keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.name;
```

_myTestRender

```
console.log('this')
console.log(item.stuff);
return (
  <Text>{item.name}</Text>
)
```

This works fine, other than the fact that it is calling _myTestRender twice for every item. In my example setup, I would expect it to call _myTestRender twice, not 4 times. Despite this, I still only see two  elements appear on my screen.

Sample console logs:

```
RENDER
Test.js:115 this
Test.js:116 (2) [{…}, {…}]
Test.js:115 this
Test.js:116 (2) [{…}, {…}]
Test.js:115 this
Test.js:116 (2) [{…}, {…}]
Test.js:115 this
Test.js:116 (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: React re-renders the components for every state or prop change even if it happens somewhere in the parents. It is totally ok. As React uses virtual DOM, it does not mean a real rendering in the "DOM" (or however we call it in native) unless something actually changes. As long as you get the desired result in the screen, it is OK.

Comment: Are you solve it? @A.Raduege